# Android app rep widgets: only last added is clickable

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

When I add multiple rep widgets, only last added is clickable (edx in my case, if I add another, edx become unclickable and the newly added is the only clickable rep widget).

[image]

Is it a bug?